# how do i get the $_POST to pass the variable to the next page

Tags: php

I have been working on this for days and can get it working.  I have a website that allows players to select their team from a SQL database.  I populate the drop down list using the following code.  This passes the same values to all six drop down lists.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{

        $strName = $row['FirstName']." ".$row['LastName'];
        $options.= "<OPTION Value=name>".$strName;
}


mysql_close($conn);

?>

<div  id="input_options">

<form name="form1" method="post" action="savegolfervalues.php">


<span >&nbsp; Golfer 1 </span>
    <select name="golfer1" size="1" style="font-size:15px;">
        <option value="0">Golfer 1 </option>
        <?=$options?>
    </select>
</br>

...
```

This happens for 5 different drop down lists. Ech named differently, golfer2-golfer5

```
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Set Lineup">
</form>
```

The savegolfervalues.php page just does the echo:

```
<h1>Golfer 1 is : 
<?php
$g1 = $_POST['golfer1'];
echo ($g1);
?>
</h1>
```

etc.

However--nothing gets passed across--the echo doesn't bring the names across.

What am I missing?

Comment: in your case `echo ($g1)` will print out 0 if `Golfer 1` is selected, what are you getting?

Comment: Okay. I understand that one but I'm not getting any values at all. It just shows up blank.

Comment: How would I get the value that was selected?

Comment: `$options.= "<OPTION Value=name>".$strName;` should be                `             $options.= "<option value='$strName'>".$strName."</option>";`

Comment: even making that change still get blank values

Comment: so I guess the real question then is how do I go about getting the seletec text or $strName?

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that `value` of option is passed under `$_POST['golfer1'];` and not name or label itself... so it should be `0` in your case.

```
<option value="0">Golfer 1 </option>
```

is not

```
 <option value="Golfer 1">Golfer 1 </option>
```

Comment: he has `method="post"`!!

Comment: oh sorry... removed that info about method... still rest of the post tells everything...

Comment: Method is set to post on the form. I get no values across. They are blank

Comment: the page with the echos comes up blank

Comment: Did you fix your line with unclosed `<option>` tag?

Answer (score 0):

```
$options.= "<OPTION Value=name>".$strName;
```

close option tag:

```
$options.= "<OPTION value='".$strName."'>".$strName."</OPTION>";
```

Add quotes to the attribute `value` and the variable `$strName`

Comment: `$options.= "<option value='$strName'>".$strName."</option>";`

Comment: @manta, if you want to fix anything in that code it would be better to do this this way:
`$options .= "<option value=\"{$strName}\">{$strName}</option>";`
in fact, it would be better to escape strName variable to avoid xss attacks

Comment: Thanks, escaping characters and xss attacks are out of the scope of the question.

Comment: I know, but still, worth to mention ;)